# wxPython custom progressBar problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

First of all I new to python so please do not judge me about mess in code :). I trying to make circular progress bar but I run into some problems and can't find what it causing. Problem is *setRange(0, 100) or setMmaximum(100)* not working if I setValue(100) I getting filled all circle. And second problem is my progress bar running backwards. Please can someone explain what I doing wrong?

[image]

Here what I have so far:

main.py file

```
import wx
from src.arc import TestArc


class bandom(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(800, 600))

        self.gauge = TestArc(self)
        self.gauge.SetFocus()
        #self.gauge.setMinimun(0)
        #self.gauge.setMaximun(100)
        self.gauge.setRange(0, 100)
        self.gauge.setValue(10)

       # timer for testing progressbar
  #     self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
  #     self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
  #     self.timer.Start(100)

  #     self.val = 0

 # def OnTimer(self, evt):
 #     self.val += 1
 #     self.gauge.setValue(self.val)
 #
 #     if self.val >= 100:
 #         self.val = 0
 #     #print(self.val)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
       frame = bandom(None, -1, 'Window title here')
       frame.Show(True)
       self.SetTopWindow(frame)
       return True

    def main():
       app = MyApp(0)
       app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and arc.py file

```
class TestArc(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TestArc, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.lineWidth = 0
    self.min = 0
    self.max = 100
    self._value = 0
    self.setText = '---'
    # self.font = someFont()
    self.position = wx.Rect()  # self.position.Set(x, y, width, height)
    self.startPoint = math.radians(0)
    self.endPoint = math.radians(0)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

def setRange(self, min, max):
    self.min = min
    self.max = max

    if self.max < self.min:
        self.max, self.min = self.min, self.max

    if self._value < self.min:
        self._value = self.min
    elif self._value > self.max:
        self._value = self.max

    self.Refresh()

def setMinimun(self, min):
    self.setRange(min, self.max)

def setMaximun(self, max):
    self.setRange(self.min, max)

def setValue(self, val):
    if self._value != val:
        if val < self.min:
            self._value = self.min
        elif val > self.max:
            self._value = self.max
        else:
            self._value = val
        self.Refresh()


    self.Refresh()

def setLineWidth(self, lineWidth):
    self.lineWidth = lineWidth

def setPosition(self, x, y, width, height):
    self.position = wx.Rect(x, y, width, height)

def OnPaint(self, event=None):
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    gc = self.MakeGC(dc)
    self.Draw(gc)

def MakeGC(self, dc):
    try:
        if False:
            gcr = wx.GraphicsRenderer.GetCairoRenderer
            gc = gcr() and gcr().CreateContext(dc)
            if gc is None:
                wx.MessageBox("Unable to create Cairo Context.", "Oops")
                gc = wx.GraphicsContext.Create(dc)
        else:
            gc = wx.GraphicsContext.Create(dc)

    except NotImplementedError:
        dc.DrawText("This build of wxPython does not support the wx.GraphicsContext "
                    "family of classes.",
                    25, 25)
        return None
    return gc

def Draw(self, gc):

    #middle progressbar line
    radStart = math.radians(90)
    radEnd = math.radians(0)
    path = gc.CreatePath()
    path.AddArc(80, 80, 50, radStart, radEnd, True)
    pen = wx.Pen('#000000', 4)
    pen.SetCap(wx.CAP_BUTT)
    gc.SetPen(pen)
    gc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#000000', wx.TRANSPARENT))
    gc.DrawPath(path)

    #progress bar
    start = math.radians(90)
    #r = math.radians(270)
    arcStep = -270 / (self.max - self.min) * self._value
    end = math.radians(arcStep)
    path = gc.CreatePath()
    path.AddArc(80, 80, 50, start, end)
    pen = wx.Pen('#CC7F32', 15)
    pen.SetCap(wx.CAP_BUTT)
    gc.SetPen(pen)
    gc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#000000', wx.TRANSPARENT))
    gc.DrawPath(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit gruesome because you have offset everything by 90º, so you have to account for that.
Here goes nothing:

```
import wx
import math
class TestArc(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestArc, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.lineWidth = 0
        self.min = -90
        self.max = 360
        self._value = 0
        self.setText = '---'
        # self.font = someFont()
        self.position = wx.Rect()  # self.position.Set(x, y, width, height)
        self.startPoint = math.radians(0)
        self.endPoint = math.radians(0)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def setRange(self, min, max):
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
        if self._value < self.min:
            self._value = self.min
        elif self._value > self.max:
            self._value = self.max
        self.Refresh()

    def setMinimun(self, min):
        self.setRange(min, self.max)

    def setMaximun(self, max):
        self.setRange(self.min, max)

    def setValue(self, val):
        if self._value != val:
            if val < self.min:
                self._value = self.min
            elif val > self.max:
                self._value = self.max
            else:
                self._value = val
        self.Refresh()

    def setLineWidth(self, lineWidth):
        self.lineWidth = lineWidth

    def setPosition(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.position = wx.Rect(x, y, width, height)

    def OnPaint(self, event=None):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        gc = self.MakeGC(dc)
        self.Draw(gc)

    def MakeGC(self, dc):
        try:
            if False:
                gcr = wx.GraphicsRenderer.GetCairoRenderer
                gc = gcr() and gcr().CreateContext(dc)
                if gc is None:
                    wx.MessageBox("Unable to create Cairo Context.", "Oops")
                    gc = wx.GraphicsContext.Create(dc)
            else:
                gc = wx.GraphicsContext.Create(dc)
        except NotImplementedError:
            dc.DrawText("This build of wxPython does not support the wx.GraphicsContext "
                        "family of classes.",
                        25, 25)
            return None
        return gc

    def Draw(self, gc):
        #middle progressbar line
        radStart = math.radians(90)
        radEnd = math.radians(0)
        path = gc.CreatePath()
        path.AddArc(80, 80, 50, radStart, radEnd, True)
        pen = wx.Pen('#000000', 4)
        pen.SetCap(wx.CAP_BUTT)
        gc.SetPen(pen)
        gc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#000000', wx.TRANSPARENT))
        gc.DrawPath(path)

        #progress bar
        start = math.radians(90)
        #r = math.radians(270)
        arcStep = 270 / (self.max - self.min) * self._value
        end = math.radians(arcStep)
        path = gc.CreatePath()
        path.AddArc(80, 80, 50, start, end)
        pen = wx.Pen('#CC7F32', 15)
        pen.SetCap(wx.CAP_BUTT)
        gc.SetPen(pen)
        gc.SetBrush(wx.Brush('#000000', wx.TRANSPARENT))
        gc.DrawPath(path)

class bandom(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(800, 600))

        self.gauge = TestArc(self)
        self.gauge.SetFocus()
        self.gauge.setMinimun(90)
        self.gauge.setMaximun(360)
        self.gauge.setValue(90)

       # timer for testing progressbar
        self.val = 90
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(100)

    def OnTimer(self, evt):
       self.val += 2.7
       self.gauge.setValue(self.val)
       if self.val >= 360:
           self.val = 90

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = bandom(None, -1, 'Window title here')
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I shoved it all into one file for my convenience.
Edit:
The reason for changing the maximum value to 360 and calculating the Step in the Arc with 270 is that you have chosen to use a 3/4 circle for your gauge and you are calculating the amount to increment the gauge using radians. You could have used degrees or radians but either way it's going to be calculated between 0 and 270 for degrees or 0 and 3π/2 for radians. Originally you said that you required a scale between 0 and 100, the easiest way to arrange that is to increment/decrement the gauge counter by 2.7 rather than 1 i.e. 270 points to travel / 100 (your required scale). It would be easier to start the gauge at point 0 rather than 90 but I assume that you are doing this either as an exercise or for aesthetic reasons.
Your last comment regarding needing 240 increments, conflicts with the original question and other comments but can be achieved by incrementing the gauge counter by 1.125 (270/240) rather than either 1 or 2.7

Edit 2:
Running this code on my machine I get no "flicker". It could be down to the speed of your machine and may improve if you change the value that you pass to the `wx.Timer`, currently 100 milliseconds or 10 times a second. Remember that this code in essence pretends to show the progress of a task by using the timer, in reality you would be passing values into the gauge not based on a timer but on the progress of a actual process.

Comment: thank you but still goes backwards any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to. Using a compass/clock, my code starts at the bottom in the South (6), travels clockwise through West (9), then North (12) and ends at East (3). That doesn't sound "backwards"

Comment: Sorry I mistaken! Thank you very much

Comment: The direction is governed by the sign of `arcStep` I have set it as positive 270 you have it as negative. If you change it back you will have to adjust the start and end positions, I think!

Comment: Thank you! now I need to find a way how to make a range between 0 and 100 :)

Comment: Increment `self.val` by 2.7 not 1 to give yourself 100 ticks within a 270 degree distance

Comment: sorry but not sure what do you mean :) plus in my project I will need range between 0 and 240.

Comment: I think I got it! Thank you for your time and very good explanation. I will take a chance and will ask one more question - maybe can you tell why my gauge is flickering when running, this is because of 'self.Refresh'?